# How to remove categories from the all categories page in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, categories

I have a MediaWiki website and I was experimenting with categories. When you delete a page it is not shown at the All Pages as desired. However when I delete a category it remains in the All Categories page. So my question is how can I remove categories that have 0-items?

Answer (score 1):

Use a maintenance-script [Manual:CleanupEmptyCategories.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CleanupEmptyCategories.php).

Basically it means the following: SSH into your web-environment where you installed the wiki, enter the maintenance directory. Execute the following command:

```
php cleanupEmptyCategories.php
```

If you get the message:

> ...Update 'cleanup empty categories' already logged as completed.

You can force the update with the `--force` command.

```
php cleanupEmptyCategories.php --force
```